# Xpath 1.0: ancestor-or-self::NameTest/NameTest[predicate] does not work as I expect

Tags: xpath, xpath-1.0

I am dealing with an XML vocabulary that has "default values": i.e., if a node does not have a certain subnode, I'd like to find the nearest enclosing node that has that subnode, and use its string value as the value of the original node's subnode.

E.g., if I have a tree

```
Super_node
    sub_node: XXX
    ...
        context_node
            /* does not have a child with name sub_node */
```

and no intervening nodes between `Super_node` and `context_node` have a child `sub_node`, I want an expression that evaluates to `XXX`.

I was thinking that the following query should work, but I always get a node list:

```
string(ancestor-or-self::*/sub_node[1]/text())
```

My thinking is that `ancestor-or-self::*` returns, in reverse document order, the list of `context_node`, `parent_of_context_node`, ..., `Super_node`.  I apply the `sub_node` test to that, and get the list of `sub_node`s in that list, again, hopefully, in reverse document order.

I then apply the predicate `[1]`, which should return the first element of that list.  However, this predicate seems to be not effective: in my implementation (which I think is based on `libxml2`), I still receive a list.

What does work, I found after poking around on Stack Exchange a bit, is

```
string((ancestor-or-self::*/sub_node)[last()]/text())
```

Why is the predicate `[1]` above not effective?

Comment: Share real XML code sample instead of pseudo nodes tree. + current, desired output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The expression

```
ancestor-or-self::*/sub_node[1]
```

means

```
ancestor-or-self::*/(child::sub_node[1])
```

which selects the first `sub_node` element child of every ancestor element.

I suspect you were thinking of

```
(ancestor-or-self::*/sub_node)[1]
```

which selects all the `sub_node` children of all the ancestor elements, sorts them into document order, and then returns the first node in this list.

Predicates like [1] bind more strongly than "/".